# How can I get size of symbolic link in python

Tags: python

let's assume:
file
ln -s file s_file

```
os.path.getsize(s_file) or os.stat(s_file).st_size
```

will return size of real file.
I want only s_file. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

Does [`os.lstat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.lstat), which is symlink-specific, work for you?

Comment: Ooh. Nice one.I forgot about lstat()